# 2D array simulation making the character move

Tags: java, arrays, computer-science

I'm making a simulation where there is a grid/map and the user gets to pick the initial position of the character. Once the position is chosen the character randomly starts moving (the movement can be only one space at a time either up, down, right or left). The character moves 50-60 times and then stops. And if it goes around the corners of the grid and is about to go out it picks a new random number. This is what I have so far. I can't get the player to move.

```
public static String map[][] = new String[21][21];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter starting (x,y) coordinates for the player (0-20)");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // System.in is a standard input stream
    System.out.print("Enter X position: ");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Y position: ");
    int y = sc.nextInt();

    // create a 2- dimensional array
    fillGrid();

    map[x][y] = " ** "; // Letter to represent the location of the player
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = rand.nextInt(4);
    for (a = 1; a < 100; a++) { // for loop to make the player move one step at a time only
        if (a == 0) {
            y++;
        }
        else if (a == 1) {
            y--;
        }
        else if (a == 2) {
            x++;
        }
        else {
            x--;
        }
    }
    showMap();
}

public static void fillGrid() {
    // place a dot in each space of the array(grid)
    for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
            map[x][y] = "|__|";
        }
    }
}

public static void showMap() {
    // show / display the map
    for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.print(map[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop uses the same variable as your random number.  Use a different variable  Use meaningful variable names like `randomDirection` and `index`, rather an `a`.

Comment: You'll need something like an animation loop:  `show map, sleep for while, change coordinates, repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the modification in your code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{

    private  static String map[][] = new String[21][21];
    //hard coded test data 
    private static int x=4, y=5;//make x,y class variable

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fillGrid();
        map[x][y] = " ** "; // Letter to represent the location of the player
        showMap();

        Random rand = new Random();
        //animation loop
        for (int cycle = 0; cycle < 10; cycle++) {     //for loop to make the player move one step at a time only

            int direction = rand.nextInt(4);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (direction == 0) {
                y++;
            } else if (direction == 1) {
                y--;
            } else if (direction == 2) {
                x++;
            } else {
                x--;
            }
            //todo check that x,y are within grid

            System.out.println("moving player to "+ x+"-"+y);
            showMap();
        }
    }

    public static void fillGrid() {
        // place a dot in each space of the array(grid)
        for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
                map[x][y] = "|__|";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void showMap() {
        // show / display the map
        for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.print(map[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```